# HttpWebRequest gives 500 status code but is returning JSON from the API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, http-status-code-500

**Question Background:**

I am attempting to make a simple `HttpWebRequest` to a Web API that I have hosted in Azure.

**The Issue:**

If I access my Web API end point through a browser or a request tool such as Postman I am receiving a `JSON` response with no Issues.

If I try accessing the same end point through a `HttpWebRequest` Call I receive a 500 fatal error but I am able to see in the response property of the `Try Catch` that the `JSON` response has been returned.

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

**The Code:**

The following is the simple request I am making to the Web API I have. As stated before, in the `Catch` ***the response is*** returning back the `JSON` I expect, as shown:

```
{"ResponseMessage":"OK","ResponseContent:[{"kind":"youtube#playlistItem","etag":"\"gMxXHe- ........ etc }]}
```

The Request:

```
 string url ="http://myapi.azurewebsites.net/api/videos/GetYouTubeVideos";

    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

        WebResponse wr = req.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        var pageContent = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                              .ReadToEnd();
    }
```

**I appreciate that identifying the cause of a 500 isn't straight forward but can anyone provide a reason I would be getting this error but also still receiving the `JSON` from the service that is apparently throw an exception?**

Comment: Does your JSON response is valid? The response you've given is not valid..probably it because you have added just example data..second thing add your full method code and add exception to the response message!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some properties about `WebHeaders` you must be care!example codes:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.Proxy = webProxy;
webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
webRequest.Timeout = 20 * 1000;
webRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36";
WebResponse wr = webRequest.GetResponse()
```